# How to compare different objects in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have used below commands to fetch KB values from update list in that i have to check exact match of KB values i have used all the possibility of -eq -match like everything but -eq is perfect to get but its not working in my case kindly suggest.

```
$patchID="KB3039714"
$Session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"

$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
$a = $Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount) | Select-Object 
@{Name="KB";Expression={[regex]::match($_.Title,'\
(([^\)]+)\)').Groups[1].Value}}
foreach($c in $a){
if($c -eq $patchID){
$Status="True"
write-host "exe File Type"
}else{
write-host "Given patchID is not available"
}}
```

Comment: "I have used below commands" - what commands? And you can check what properties the object has using `Get-Member`.

Comment: $c.gettype() i have noticed that it doesn't return a String object, but a PSCustomObject

how to compare in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write out $c it shows:

[image]

So if you want to compare the output with the string `$patchID`,you have to compare the Attribute "KB" of the Object with your string.
Either like this:

```
$patchID="KB3039714"
$Session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"

$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
$a = $Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount) | Select-Object @{Name="KB";Expression={[regex]::match($_.Title,'\(([^\)]+)\)').Groups[1].Value}}
foreach($c in $a){
if($c.KB -eq $patchID){
$Status="True"
write-host "exe File Type"
}else{
write-host "Given patchID is not available"
}}
```

Or like this:

```
$patchID="KB3039714"
$Session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
$a = $Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount) | Select-Object 
@{Name="KB";Expression={[regex]::match($_.Title,'\(([^\)]+)\)').Groups[1].Value}}
if($a.KB.Contains($patchID)){
$Status="True"
write-host "exe File Type"
}else{
write-host "Given patchID is not available"
}}
```

Maybe you should read into Powershell-Objects a little bit more, this Article explains it very well: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730946.aspx